# DataReader get type specification SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a small program to "download" database tables to Excel.

I want to add the column type to the second line and I tried it with the following function. It works fine but the `GetDataTypeName(i)` returns only `int, nvarchar` but I need the complete type specification like this

```
nvarchar(255), decimal(19, 8)
```

Is there another function to get this from the database ?

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

// adds the names and the types if the table has no values
if (!dataReader.HasRows || !withValues)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        names.Add(dataReader.GetName(i));
        types.Add(dataReader.GetDataTypeName(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those questions seem to address getting the size/precision of the field. `dataReader.GetSchemaTable()` gives you full metadata for all columns.

Comment: For the size go via [`.GetSchemaTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx)  (Not sure if it exposes precision/scale however)

Comment: You don't need that information to export a table to Excel. Either use SQL Server's own SSIS or use a library like EPPlus to generate a real Excel (ie `xlsx`) file with a call as simple as `sheet.LoadFromDataTable` as shown [here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample). You can format the resulting columns as needed

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed, although the second one did ask for it!

Comment: @AlexK. It does - they're called `NumericPrecision` and `NumericScale` listed on the documentation you linked

Comment: Note that Excel doesn't have types, so knowing the database precision won't help a lot. It only stores text or numeric values and displays them using a specific format. Eg, dates are doubles displayed using a date format.

Comment: Voted to reopen the question because the duplicates don't answer the question about the field size.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : yes i know and i convert them, the "complete" type is only for me to see how many chars i can use...the excel will will converts back to an sql script

Comment: @kb_ the point is that you don't have to do anything to get a real Excel file, as opposed to CSV or HTML tables with a fake `xlsx` extension. No conversions are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of information is available through the call [GetSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns a DataTable where you have a row for each column returned by the query. Each column of this table describe a particular information extracted by the  metadata relative to the query field

For example

```
    SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (!dataReader.HasRows || !withValues)
    {
        DataTable dt = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ColumnName: " + row.Field<string>("ColumnName"));
            Console.WriteLine("NET Type: " + row.Field<string>("DataTypeName"));
            Console.WriteLine("Size: " + row.Field<int>("ColumnSize"));
        }
   }
```

The GetSchemaTable returns a lot of information about your table/query, but a lot of these fields are set to null. I am not sure if this is a limitation of the provider or they are null because, in the context of the call, they have no meaning. In any case use defensive programming in accessing these values (if !(value == DBNull.Value)

Comment: thanks for that! short question, when i have a decimal like this decimal(19,8) can i get this in the same way ? at the moment he says for the decimal (19,8) the following --> decimal(17)

Comment: Uhm, the values should be in NumericPrecision and NumericScale, but I need to check

Comment: Yes, ColumnSize is 17 but NumericPrecision get 19 and NumericScale = 8, so if you have a decimal type you should look at these two columns. I think that the explanation is in the description for ColumnSize: _For columns that use a fixed-length data type, this is the size of the data type._

Answer (score 4):

Please using TableSchema method for getting all details of column .

```
SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();

using (var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string ColumnName= row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
            string DataTypeName= row.Field<string>("DataTypeName");
            short NumericPrecision= row.Field<short>("NumericPrecision");
            short NumericScale= row.Field<short>("NumericScale");
            int ColumnSize= row.Field<int>("ColumnSize");
            Console.WriteLine("Column: {0} Type: {1} Precision: {2} Scale: {3} ColumnSize {4}",      
            ColumnName, DataTypeName, NumericPrecision, scale,ColumnSize);
        }
    }
```

Thanks .